# Temp Table Inner Join Slow Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `temp` table which has column PID. I have another `table` where all PID are stored. But when I do `inner join` on PID it is very slow.
What idea do you have to optimize the code ?

Temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    [PID] [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL, 
)
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PIDs]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [PID] [nvarchar] (20) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PIDs_PID] 
    ON [dbo].[PIDs] ([PID]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #tmp
INNER JOIN dbo.PIDs AS cft ON cft.PID  = c.PID
```

The records in temp table are 200000. The records in physical table are 400000.

Comment: Not enough info. Try creating index on temp table too.

Comment: How many records are present in `#tmp` and `PIDs` table.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem comes from the facts that your temp table isn't indexed.  You have two `nvarchar` columns (of varying widths) which every lookup has to be a table scan.  To speed things up, you should create an index on your temp table, or you could even make it the primary key.  If it's a look up, there is no need to have duplicates.

There are other possibilities too, but there isn't enough information in the question to to discern.  Is this in a stored procedure?  Are multiple processes calling it simultaneously?